# How can I obtain a remote drive's free space, for SQL Server to write a .BAK file, via a command run from within SQL Server?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I need to run a program which needs to find how much free space I have in a specific drive ( `unc` or `regular`)

I need it to work under `CMD`.( no ps)

Goal :

```
c:\> something e:
     1902323213 //nevermind mb /gb
```

*please notice : numbers only ! I dont have the tool to deal with strings ( in my soft)*

So what have I tried ?

I've tried this :

`DIR \\dsmain\ls_BackUp\*.* | find "free"`

which yields :

`2 Dir(s)  311,285,014,528 bytes free`

I've also tried this : (worst)

`fsutil volume diskfree c:`

which yields :

```
Total # of free bytes        : 54761066496
Total # of bytes             : 255953203200
Total # of avail free bytes  : 54761066496
```

**Question :**

Using cmd (no ps) - how can I run a command which returns **only** the free space of a drive ?

nb :

Sql server needs to open a bak file on remote location and i need to check free space there , so sql execute cmd command and i can capture the result . So i dont want to start using string manipulations to extract the number

Comment: What are you trying to do that getting the free space from a command window is the solution? (There may be a easier way to do it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command line tool `wmic` to query `Win32_LogicalDisk`

```
wmic LOGICALDISK where name="C:" get freespace
```

That will return two lines in the format

```
FreeSpace
2881409024
```

or

`wmic LOGICALDISK where name="C:" get freespace | find /v "Free"`

which yields just the number

Comment: Sql server needs to open a bak file on remote location and i need to check free space there , so sql execute cmd command and i can capture the result . So i dont want to start using string manipulations to extract the number .... The first solution however its multiple statements .... Yours is once but you have 2 lines ... Cant you find away to return please only the second row ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir if that is all you want to do you can use the built in stored procedure `xp_fixeddrives` just do `exec master..xp_fixeddrives`. Things like this is why it is important to ask your real problem, not asking about your problem you have with the solution you came up with to your question ([The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: - not on remote locations ( I did used it locally when I restore the bak  - but when I need to SAVE the bak on remote location I need to validate if it has a free space.) this command(which i know) is not helping for remote locations. ( and dont tell me to use map network drive:-))

Comment: In that case look at [this blog post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3037/getting-more-details-with-an-enhanced-xpfixeddrives-for-sql-server/) the poster uses a similar wmic command to what I posted in my answer and turns it in to a stored procedure, you can tweak his code if you need to do execute whatever wmic command that you need and get a result in a table structure that will let you filter and choose whatever columns from the result you need.

Comment: @tnx , i will try extract the second line from your statement (and ofcourse will look at your link)

Comment: Scott - wait  , this is not working with the UNC path.... only local . can you please reply /

Comment: I don't know WMI well enough to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The below returns JUST the free space in bytes.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do (
    set bytesfree=%%a
)
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
echo %bytesfree%
endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%
pause>nul
```

Comment: this is not working. (win8 cmd)

Comment: Manually replacing a hard-coded thousand separator is not a good idea, especially considering it can be different in non-English locales, and it can be further customized by users. Better use the `/-c` parameter to remove those separators entirely. Also, single quotes aren't enough when the target path contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line command you can use in a command prompt:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %G in ('"dir /-c "\\dsmain\ls_BackUp\" "') do @set free=%G
```

To display the free space value you can `echo` it:

```
echo %free%
```

### How it works

The output of the `dir` command is parsed line by line till the end. The last line is always the one which contains the free space amount, unless the path is invalid. To avoid having to deal with thousands separators (which are locale-aware, and can be customized), you need to use the `/-c` parameter to strip them entirely. Each line gets [tokenized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) by using spaces as separators, and the third token is then assigned to the `%free%` variable each time.